# What is the python's "urllib2" equivalent in dot net?

Tags: c#, bots

I am new in python. I wanna build a bot in c#. Can i use this "urllib2" in dot net or is there any alternative in dot net? please help...

Answer (score 4):

Most of the equivalent functionality is in [System.Web](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.aspx) namespace:

> The System.Web namespace supplies classes and interfaces that enable browser-server communication. This namespace includes the  HttpRequest class, which provides extensive information about the current HTTP request; the  HttpResponse class, which manages HTTP output to the client; and the  HttpServerUtility class, which provides access to server-side utilities and processes. System.Web also includes classes for cookie manipulation, file transfer, exception information, and output cache control.

A close cousin of `urlopen` is the [System.Net.Webclient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class:

> Provides common methods for sending data to and receiving data from a resource identified by a URI.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        if (args == null || args.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException ("Specify the URI of the resource to retrieve.");
        }
        WebClient client = new WebClient ();

        // Add a user agent header in case the 
        // requested URI contains a query.

        client.Headers.Add ("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");

        Stream data = client.OpenRead (args[0]);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (data);
        string s = reader.ReadToEnd ();
        Console.WriteLine (s);
        data.Close ();
        reader.Close ();
    }
}
```

Comment: @gimel , i already use this code in various parts of my projects. thanks for this . But i need the urllib2.build_opener([handler, ...]) functionality of the following page.
 http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html
 Can you provide me any clue how to use this in dot net?

Comment: Sorry, no multi-handler model in HttpWebRequest. Some properties provide similar functions, e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.proxy.aspx

Comment: @Tareq: Why didn't you ask that in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [HttpRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx) and/or [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx). Or, you may need to use [sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx). It depends on what kind of bot you want to build.

Also, there is a python implementation for .NET called [IronPython](http://www.codeplex.com/IronPython). This is able to use standard python libraries and the .NET framework as well.

---

On a side note I'd recommend you to choose the right language/framework *after* you found out what you want to do and observed the alternatives, not before that.

Answer (score 0):

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/dotnet/ could help also.